# Как на языке с++ осуществить перезагрузку системы Linux?

Tags: c++, linux

Ядро версии 3.10.32.
Как вариант, как в принципе запускать bash скрипты или бинарники?

Comment: сначала нужно создать пользователя с рут правами, скомпилировать и запускать от имени данного пользователя. запустить можно с `system("/sbin/reboot");`

Answer (score 2):

Функция и макрос полной перезагрузки Linux описан [здесь](https://sourceware.org/git/?p=glibc.git;a=blob;f=sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/sys/reboot.h;h=686fa39ae9d9495d1d19083393617a419be074ca;hb=refs/heads/master) как `#define RB_AUTOBOOT   0x01234567`. Благодаря `glibc` вы можете передать константу макроса `RB_AUTOBOOT` для выполнения перезагрузки.

**P.S** Учтите, при перезагрузке не происходит сихронизация, поэтому данные могут быть потеряны.

**Пример:**

```cpp
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/reboot.h>

sync();
reboot(RB_AUTOBOOT);
```

Comment: чтобы это работало, программа должна иметь привелегию `CAP_SYS_BOOT`